# Group by de un DataRow para que lo retorne a mi DataSet

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo el siguiente ciclo para que cada vez que me recorra el `DataRow` agregue el valor que le toca mas "`:00`" y otro igual con "`:30`", el tema esta en que me repite los valores que ya tengo por defecto y quiero generar un `group by` para que me retorne los valores que quiero solo una vez:

```
for (int ii = 1; ii <= 24; ii++)
{
    DataRow dr = rs.Tables[0].NewRow();
    rs.Tables[0].Rows.Add((ii < 10 ? "0" : "") + ii.ToString() + ":00");
    rs.Tables[0].Rows.Add((ii < 10 ? "0" : "") + ii.ToString() + ":30");
    dr.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("Grupo")); 
}
```

Comment: Cuales son los valores que tienes por defecto y cuales serian los valores que quieres? no entiendo tu pregunta, no esta muy claro.
Creo que deberías aclarar y agregar detalles de exactamente que quieres y cual es el problema.
Otra cosa que no entiendo, si quieres que te retorne los valores de `group by` solo una vez por que esta dentro del loop?
Si esta dentro de un metodo que retorna un valor especifico deberías sacar DataRow del loop (arriba), usarlo dentro del loop y retornar `dr.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("Grupo")); ` afuera del loop (abajo)

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que te faltan detalles en la pregunta, no logro entenderlo del todo, pero viendo tu codigo jamas iba a funcionar creando un DataRow en cada iteracion del loop, mucho menos devolviendo el valor tambien en cada iteracion, segun la logica general solo deberia estar en el loop los metodos Add() de los Rows.
Sinceramente no estoy seguro si te entendi bien, pero prueba con esto:

```
DataRow dr = rs.Tables[0].NewRow();
for (int ii = 1; ii <= 24; ii++)
{
    rs.Tables[0].Rows.Add((ii < 10 ? "0" : "") + ii.ToString() + ":00");
    rs.Tables[0].Rows.Add((ii < 10 ? "0" : "") + ii.ToString() + ":30");
}
return dr.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("Grupo"));
```

Si no es lo que estas buscando entonces por favor intenta agregar mas detalles a tu pregunta, se mas claro.